# spring security weird redirection

Tags: redirect, spring-security, configuration

I have this spring security configuration and the controller is the one I show. Its really simply... The /form loads the form and the others are JSP that only load a page with a string like the filename.
I am having a weird behaviour I havent experienced before like:
If I hit http://localhost:1111/preferences, it redirects to /form but it shows a 404.Other scenario I faced yesterday is that I login correctly (At least at code level), but it redirects to /home but doesnt show the correct screen.
]Does anyone know what is this all about ?.

```
    @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable()
               .authorizeRequests()

                    .antMatchers("/form").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/history").hasAuthority("EMPLOYEE")
                    .antMatchers("/home").hasAuthority("EMPLOYEE")
                    .antMatchers("/live").hasAuthority("EMPLOYEE")
                    .antMatchers("/management").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN")
                    .antMatchers("/preferences").hasAuthority("EMPLOYEE")
                    .antMatchers("/api/**").hasAuthority("EMPLOYEE")
                    .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/form")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/home", true)
            .usernameParameter("username")
            .passwordParameter("password")
            .failureHandler(new CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler());

}
```

and

```
    @GetMapping(value = {"/form"})
public ModelAndView login() {
    return new ModelAndView("form");
}

@GetMapping(value = {"/history"})
public ModelAndView history() {
    return new ModelAndView("history");
}

@GetMapping(value = {"/home"})
public ModelAndView home() {
    return new ModelAndView("home");
}

@GetMapping(value = {"/live"})
public ModelAndView live() {
    return new ModelAndView("live");
}

@GetMapping(value = {"/management"})
public ModelAndView management() {
    return new ModelAndView("management");
}

@GetMapping(value = {"/preferences"})
public ModelAndView preferences() {
    return new ModelAndView("preferences");
}
```

Comment: Does the login form properly load if you just navigate to http://localhost:1111/form? Only redirection causes this issue?

Comment: Hey hi... how are you ?... I solved the issue... I was integrating react into spring boot and I forgot that I was using a redirect filter to handle routing from both... so it was always redirecting badly... jaja I mean the first time I load the app I need this filter and afterwards I handle things through react routing...